# PetaPoco Partial Update

Tags: c#, .net, petapoco

Is Anybody having petapoco source code with partial update? 
According to the petapoco document, this feature should be there.

http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/116/PetaPoco-Partial-Record-Updates

But I've downloaded the source code from github but the partial update is missing.
If someone has the source code with partial update, please share with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two "versions" of the partial update method in the current version on Github (maybe you need to pull the changes). 
One is on the Database class:

```
public int Update(object poco, IEnumerable<string> columns)
```

Github: https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/blob/adfbde3207a94d0de5c74188d8d1b5801a8be0b9/PetaPoco/PetaPoco.cs#L1433 line number 1443

Usage: `db.Update(u, new string[] { "last_login" });` where db is an instance of `Database`

And the the another one is in the [TT generated Record](http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/71/PetaPoco-T4-Template) class:

```
public int Update(IEnumerable<string> columns) { return repo.Update(this, columns); }
```

Github:  https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/blob/adfbde3207a94d0de5c74188d8d1b5801a8be0b9/PetaPoco/Models/Generated/PetaPoco.Generator.ttinclude#L73 line number 73

Usage : `u.Update(new string[] { "last_login" });` where u is a TT generated `Record<T>`

Comment: I'm not using TT generated record. Would it be able to able to track modified columns in normal way?

Comment: No it won't track the changes if you are using POCOs. However you can create your own base class and copy the change tracking code from the TT generated record.

Comment: Can you please update the github links? They both go to 404 now.

Comment: @RyanGates I fixed to links to point to the specific commit. The code is organized quite differently now (this answer is 7 years old now) so I have no idea where to find these methods in the new codebase.